# Python marshmallow parameter in nested

Tags: python, marshmallow

I've been using the library for a short time. I've been searching, but I can't solve a problem.

I have two Schemas:

```
class SonSchema(Schema):
    paramter1 = fields.Str
    parameter2 = fields.Str

class FatherSchema(Schema):
    son = fields.Nested(SonSchema)
```

Then I have the load function:

```
flag = True
schema = FatherSchema().load(response)
```

What I need is depending on the parameter Flag in the SonSchema validate some parameter, for example if flag = True then parameter1 needs to be in the response (with a @validation_schema).

I really don't know how to pass the parameter in the schema instance to get the SonSchema. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Hi, no, it’s a external parameter to SonSchema and FatherSchema

Answer (score 0):

You might be better off using different schemas depending on `flag`. You can use inheritance to minimize duplication.

```py
class SonSchema(Schema):
    paramter1 = fields.Str
    parameter2 = fields.Str

class FatherSchema(Schema):
    son = fields.Nested(SonSchema)

class ValidatedSonSchema(SonSchema):
    @validates_schema
    def validation_method(self, data, kwargs):
        ...

class ValidatedFatherSchema(FatherSchema):
    son = fields.Nested(ValidatedSonSchema)

flag = True
schema = ValidateFatherSchema if flag else FatherSchema
result = schema().load(response)
```

Answer (score 0):

Jérôme's answer is correct but if you want to use only one schema to validate some case you can always set schema context and then inside validation method check what you want based on flag inside context:

```
class SonSchema(Schema):
  parameter1 = fields.Str()
  parameter2 = fields.Str()

  @validates_schema
  def validate_parameters(self, data, **kwargs):
    is_flag = self.context.get('flag', False)
    print(self.context)
    # Parameters validation based on flag
```

You can set context for FatherSchema and you will be to able to use it inside son nested schema:

```
schema = FatherSchema(context={'flag': True})
data = {'son': {'parameter1': 'parameter1 value', 'parameter2': 'parameter2 value'}}
schema.load(data)
```

Please visit [Extending Schemas](https://marshmallow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/extending.html?highlight=context#using-context) and [Schema](https://marshmallow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/marshmallow.schema.html#schema) documentation pages for more information.